# C# Return Value, But keep getting error. Why?

Tags: c#

Hello fellow stackoverflow members!

I'm very new to the C# language transfer from Java, Obj-C.
It looks pretty same as Java, but I have trouble issue in very simple thing.
I have created two individual class files, Class-A and Class-Human.

### Specification for Class-A

it contains the static main method declared.And I've tried to create the new instance of Class-Human.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
      Human human = new Human("Yoon Lee", 99);
      int expected = human.getNetID; //<-gets the error at this moment.
}
```

### Specification for Class-Human

```
namespace Class-A
{
    public class Human
    {
        public String name;
        public int netId;

        public Human(String name, int netId)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.netId = netId;
        }
     public int getNetID()
     {
         return netId;
     }
}
```

Why can't copy over into local variable?
The compiler prompts me the error of

```
'Cannot convert method group of 'getNetID' delegate blah blah'
```

Thank you.

Comment: You miss } to close namespace, also getNetID returns String but you try to assign it to int (expected) and mainly - you define method getNetID() but use it as property

Comment: Have you tried VB.NET?  It's a much better fit for this kind of code.  It will readily let you convert between strings and ints, scoping is much clearer with explicit words rather than punctuation.  Recommended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the method-call to:

```
int expected = human.getNetID();
```

In C#, method-calls require parantheses `()` containing a comma-separated list of arguments. In this case, the `getNetID` method is parameterless; but the empty parantheses are still required to indicate that your intention is to *invoke* the method (as opposed to, for example, converting the method-group to a delegate-type).

Additionally, as others have pointed out, there is a mismatch betweem the return-type of the method and the variable you're assigning its value to, which you're going to have to resolve *somehow* (change both the field-type and method return-type to `int` / parse the string as an integer, etc.).

On another note, C# natively supports [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28VS.71%29.aspx) for getter-setter semantics, so the idiomatic way of writing this would be something like:

```
//hyphens are not valid in identifiers
namespace ClassA
{
    public class Human
    {
        // these properties are publicly gettable but can only be set privately
        public string Name { get; private set; } 
        public int NetId { get; private set; }

        public Human(string name, int netId)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.NetId = netId;
        }

        // unlike Java, the entry-point Main method begins with a capital 'M'
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Human human = new Human("Yoon Lee", 99);
            int expected = human.NetId; // parantheses not required for property-getter
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it works. this was the stupidest mistake i ever made wa haha. probably, what eclipse gave me lazy auto type made me this mistake. ;- ) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a method as if it's a property. You need parenthesis and to convert the string to int, or just make `getNetID` return an `int`.

I think you meant:

```
public int getNetID()
{
  return netId;
}
```

Or better still, use automatic properties:

```
public int NetId {get; private set;}  //Notice Making N in Net capital
```

And then:

```
int expected = human.getNetID();
```

This will do the trick (-:

Answer (score 0):

It should be `human.getNetID()`

*Edit:* And yes, as Oren says - you should change your netId getter to return `int`. I assume that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
Human human = new Human("Yoon Lee", 99);
int expected = human.getNetID(); //<-gets the error at this moment.
```

you need to add parentheses after the method call.

The way you have it right now you are fetcing the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I see that netId is integer.

```
getNetID() return type is string.
```

return type is not matching.

Answer (score 0):

netID is declared as an Int:

```
public int netId;
```

but your function getNetID returns a string:

```
public String getNetID()
```

Therefore, the body of getNetID makes no sense when it tried to return an int as a string:

```
return netId;
```